# X11 + OpenGL causes segfault

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, x11

I'm having issues getting X11 to work with OpenGL. I've tried everything! It used to work with GLFW but I'm trying to get it to work with GLX instead, and Win32 currently works, so this is very system-dependent. Why does the program segfault when it reaches either glClear, glClearColor, or glGetString? Thanks in advance!

This all lies inside a function, Initialize(), of a class X11Window. There is barely any code that happens before. I have NVidia drivers installed.

```
display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
if (display == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Could not open display\n";
    return 1;
}
screen = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(display);
screenId = DefaultScreen(display);


// Check GLX version
GLint majorGLX, minorGLX = 0;
glXQueryVersion(display, &majorGLX, &minorGLX);
if (majorGLX <= 1 && minorGLX < 2) {
    std::cout << "GLX 1.2 or greater is required.\n";
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 1;
}
else {
    std::cout << "GLX client version: " << glXGetClientString(display, GLX_VERSION) << '\n';
    std::cout << "GLX client vendor: " << glXGetClientString(display, GLX_VENDOR) << "\n";
    std::cout << "GLX client extensions:\n\t" << glXGetClientString(display, GLX_EXTENSIONS) << "\n";

    std::cout << "GLX server version: " << glXQueryServerString(display, screenId, GLX_VERSION) << "\n";
    std::cout << "GLX server vendoe: " << glXQueryServerString(display, screenId, GLX_VENDOR) << "\n";
    std::cout << "GLX server extensions:\n\t " << glXQueryServerString(display, screenId, GLX_EXTENSIONS) << "\n";
}

GLint glxAttribs[] = {
    GLX_X_RENDERABLE    , True,
    GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE   , GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
    GLX_RENDER_TYPE     , GLX_RGBA_BIT,
    GLX_X_VISUAL_TYPE   , GLX_TRUE_COLOR,
    GLX_RED_SIZE        , 8,
    GLX_GREEN_SIZE      , 8,
    GLX_BLUE_SIZE       , 8,
    GLX_ALPHA_SIZE      , 8,
    GLX_DEPTH_SIZE      , 24,
    GLX_STENCIL_SIZE    , 8,
    GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER    , True,
    None
};

int fbcount;
GLXFBConfig* fbc = glXChooseFBConfig(display, screenId, glxAttribs, &fbcount);
if (fbc == 0) {
    std::cout << "Failed to retrieve framebuffer.\n";
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 1;
}
std::cout << "Found " << fbcount << " matching framebuffers.\n";

// Pick the FB config/visual with the most samples per pixel
std::cout << "Getting best XVisualInfo\n";
int best_fbc = -1, worst_fbc = -1, best_num_samp = -1, worst_num_samp = 999;
for (int i = 0; i < fbcount; ++i) {
    XVisualInfo *vi = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( display, fbc[i] );
    if ( vi != 0) {
        int samp_buf, samples;
        glXGetFBConfigAttrib( display, fbc[i], GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, &samp_buf );
        glXGetFBConfigAttrib( display, fbc[i], GLX_SAMPLES       , &samples  );
        //std::cout << "  Matching fbconfig " << i << ", SAMPLE_BUFFERS = " << samp_buf << ", SAMPLES = " << samples << ".\n";

        if ( best_fbc < 0 || (samp_buf && samples > best_num_samp) ) {
            best_fbc = i;
            best_num_samp = samples;
        }
        if ( worst_fbc < 0 || !samp_buf || samples < worst_num_samp )
            worst_fbc = i;
        worst_num_samp = samples;
    }
    XFree( vi );
}
std::cout << "Best visual info index: " << best_fbc << "\n";
GLXFBConfig bestFbc = fbc[ best_fbc ];
XFree( fbc ); // Make sure to free this!

XVisualInfo* visual = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( display, bestFbc );

if (visual == 0) {
    std::cout << "Could not create correct visual window.\n";
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 1;
}

if (screenId != visual->screen) {
    std::cout << "screenId(" << screenId << ") does not match visual->screen(" << visual->screen << ").\n";
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 1;

}

// Open the window
XSetWindowAttributes windowAttribs;
windowAttribs.border_pixel = BlackPixel(display, screenId);
windowAttribs.background_pixel = WhitePixel(display, screenId);
windowAttribs.override_redirect = True;
windowAttribs.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, RootWindow(display, screenId), visual->visual, AllocNone);
windowAttribs.event_mask = ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | KeymapStateMask | PointerMotionMask | ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask | EnterWindowMask | LeaveWindowMask;
window = XCreateWindow(display, RootWindow(display, screenId), 0, 0, game.settings.resolution.x, game.settings.resolution.y, 0, visual->depth, InputOutput, visual->visual, CWBackPixel | CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWEventMask, &windowAttribs);

// Create GLX OpenGL context
glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glXCreateContextAttribsARB = 0;
glXCreateContextAttribsARB = (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc) glXGetProcAddressARB( (const GLubyte *) "glXCreateContextAttribsARB" );

const char *glxExts = glXQueryExtensionsString( display,  screenId );
std::cout << "Late extensions:\n\t" << glxExts << "\n\n";
if (glXCreateContextAttribsARB == 0) {
    std::cout << "glXCreateContextAttribsARB() not found.\n";
}

int context_attribs[] = {
    GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB,  3,
    GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB,  3,
GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB,      0,
GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,   GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
    None
};

GLXContext context = 0;
if (!isExtensionSupported( glxExts, "GLX_ARB_create_context")) {
    context = glXCreateNewContext( display, bestFbc, GLX_RGBA_TYPE, 0, True );
}
else {
    context = glXCreateContextAttribsARB( display, bestFbc, 0, true, context_attribs );
}
XSync( display, False );

// Verifying that context is a direct context
if (!glXIsDirect (display, context)) {
    std::cout << "Indirect GLX rendering context obtained\n";
}
else {
    std::cout << "Direct GLX rendering context obtained\n";
}
glXMakeCurrent(display, window, context);

game.HandleMessage(ENGINE_MESSAGE_CONSOLE, ENGINE_MESSAGE_OUTPUT, "TEST: Made Current...\n");


std::cout << "GL Vendor: " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << "\n";
std::cout << "GL Renderer: " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << "\n";
std::cout << "GL Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << "\n";
std::cout << "GL Shading Language: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << "\n";


// Show the window
XClearWindow(display, window);
XMapRaised(display, window);
game.HandleMessage(ENGINE_MESSAGE_CONSOLE, ENGINE_MESSAGE_OUTPUT, "TEST: Made ClearWindow...\n");

// Set GL Sample stuff
glClearColor(0.5f, 0.6f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
game.HandleMessage(ENGINE_MESSAGE_CONSOLE, ENGINE_MESSAGE_OUTPUT, "TEST:ClearColor...\n");


// Resize window
/*unsigned int change_values = CWWidth | CWHeight;
XWindowChanges values;
values.width = game.settings.resolution.x;
values.height = game.settings.resolution.y;
XConfigureWindow(display, window, change_values, &values);*/

// Enter message loop
while (true) {
    ReadEvents();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

// Cleanup
XDestroyWindow(display, window);
XCloseDisplay(display);

game.HandleMessage(ENGINE_MESSAGE_CONSOLE, ENGINE_MESSAGE_OUTPUT, "TEST: X11 Window Created...\n");
return true;
```

Comment: UPDATE: Added a check for glXMakeCururent. It returns true, though. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you have a segfault, get the full backtrace. If you use some GL loader, also make sure that it did not define those functions to some function pointers which are now not properly initialized.

Comment: I´m not so sure XClearWindow and glClearColor can be called without explicit sync (Xsync). Are you sure about this?

Comment: Guys, I did a bunch of changes, but I think what got it to work was using GL3W/GLEW. I tried it after seeing that non-linked OpenGL worked. Thanks for trying, guys! For anyone interested, check out: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/677768-x11-opengl-causes-segfault/